# Making vscode snippets only trigger after specific characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I have a bunch of functions below:

> library.object1.function1()
>
> library.object1.function2()
>
> library.object2.function1()
>
> library.object2.function2()
>
> library.object3.function1()
>
> library.object3.function2()

With what they provide in current custom snippet, when I type `lib`, it will show all those above functions, which will be a mess if there are too many functions.

I want to make my snippets work like what they did in default code completion:

- When I type `lib`, it only shows:

> library

- When I type `library.`, it shows:

> object1
>
> object2
>
> object3

- When I type `library.object1.`, it shows

> function1()
>
> function2()

- Also, if I type `lib`, and leave it there, then comeback and add `rary`, the snippet doesn't work at all, I want it to continue the completion.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: What is the "current custom snippet" you mention?  From some extension you have installed?

Comment: @Mark it's how vscode allow user to create their own custom snippet: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is something like this (using javascript.json snippet file as an example):

```
"my library": {
  "prefix": "lib",
  "body": [
    "library.${1|object1,object2,object3|}.${2|function1,function2,function3,function4|}()",
  ],
  "description": "my library functions" 
}
```

With that, when you type `lib` you get only the `library` suggested completion.  <kbd>Tab</kbd> and you will get all the `object` choices you included in the snippet in the suggestion panel.  <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and will get the `function` options that you listed in the snippet.

See [snippet choices](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_choice).

Comment: Great idea. It isn't exactly what I want, but it's good enough. Thank you Mark!